# aligning matplotlib subplots legends

Tags: matplotlib, subplot

I have a few subplots for which one has less curves (see figure).
I want the legend of the second plot to be at the same height as the others. Switching the order of the two handles is not a valid option.

Thanks guys!
[image]

Comment: Welcome to [so]! At this site you are expected to try to **write the code yourself**. After **[doing more research](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592)** if you have a problem you can **post what you've tried** with a **clear explanation of what isn't working** and providing a [**Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](//stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). I suggest reading [ask] a good question and [the perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/). Also, be sure to take the [tour] and read **[this](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/347937/)**.

Answer (score 1):

After a lot of trials, I added a dummy curve:

```
axarr[1].plot([], [], label=" ", c="w")
```

[image]