# How to 'bottom' align within matplotlib multi column legend?

Tags: matplotlib, alignment, legend

Given a multi column legend created like this:

```
plot.fig.legend(handles, labels, ncol=2 ....)
```

**Is there a way to define the inner alignment?**

I'm getting a legend that has a `'top'` alignment:

[image: legend with top alignment]

But I wish for a `'bottom'` alignment like this:

[image: legend with bottom alignment]

Their is a similar question that never received an answer here:
[aligning matplotlib subplots legends](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43833721/aligning-matplotlib-subplots-legends)

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44575560/centering-matplotlib-legend-entries-within-incomplete-unfilled-rows

Comment: @Sheldore it wasn't quite the same question but the answer helped me nonetheless. Thanks.

Comment: The idea to link with Dupe was to mainly get the idea. Glad that it worked out well.

Answer (score 0):

The question that @Sheldore linked to, was different but its solution similar.

I could adopt it for my issue.

```
handles.insert(2, plt.plot([], [], color=(0, 0, 0, 0), label=" ")[0])
labels.insert(2, '')
plot.fig.legend(handles, labels, ncol=2, ....)
```

The idea is that the legend is table like. If you want an element to move to a different position you have to fill in an empty entry into the other positions.